# delooping of a monad

Tags: category-theory

Let $K$ be a bicategory and $A$ be an object of $K$, then a monad over $A$ is equivalently a monoidal object $M$ in $K(A,A)$.
As a monoid, $M$ is equivalently given as the hom object $BM(\bullet,\bullet)$ of its delooping $BM$.

My question is this: what do the morphisms in $BM(\bullet,\bullet)$ correspond to?

We can at least tell the following about them. Let $f \in BM(\bullet,\bullet)$, then precomposing by $f$ is an endomorphism on $BM(\bullet,\bullet)$.
Since $M$ is a functor on $A$, it follows that these morphisms correspond to natural transformations of $M$ to itself.

So we have this family of natural transformations, and we can speak of of the monad as a monoid -- in a more traditional sense -- of composition among them.

What do these natural transformations correspond to? Can we describe them in terms of the Kleisli structure? For example, what would they be for the maybe monad? The writer monad?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't deloop a monad. When people speak of delooping monoids, they are talking about monoids in $\textbf{Set}$.

Comment: It is a bit of a stretch, but in a sense you can think of the delooping of M as the lax functor it is equivalent to. Giving a monad M in K, as you probably know, is equivalent to give a lax functor from the terminal bicategory to K.